# google chart api

Tags: c#, charts, google-visualization

I'm using the [Google Chart API wrapper](http://code.google.com/p/googlechartsharp/wiki/ChartData).

I didn't see the option to set the labels for x-axis. I want the graph to look something like [this](http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/4097/test213.jpg).

I want to set the X labels.

Please help me figure out how to accomplish that.

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE:**

Found Solution: `T..` are the values of the x-axis on the bottom.

```
lineChart.AddAxis(
  new ChartAxis(
    ChartAxisType.Bottom,
    new string[] { "T1", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6" }
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps you

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart
   ?chxt=y
   &chbh=a
   &chs=300x225
   &cht=bvg
   &chco=A2C180,3D7930
   &chd=s:s,J
   &chdl=yes+no|no
   &chtt=Vertical+bar+chart